# Is it possible to place the header row of a JViewport at the bottom?

Tags: java, swing

I'm using a JViewport for viewing some data and I'd like the header row to be placed at the bottom of the JViewport rather than the top.

The viewport never scrolls horizontally so the issue of where the scroll bar would go isn't a problem.

I suspect I'm going to have to make my own JViewport-like class which has the header row at the bottom; but before I go off and write that I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a panel with a BorderLayout. Add the table to the scrollpane, then add the scrollpane to the center of the panel. Then get the header and add it to the south. Then get the vertical scrollbar and add it to the east.